# Minimze min max (A*x)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

has this example matrix A some special propertries, which might be useful?
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
    3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & 3 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    5 & 4 & 3 & 0 &-2 &-1 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 0 &-2 &-1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 0 &-2 &-1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-2
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I want to find $$\min \|Ax\|_\max$$
where x is a binary vector and for each Block [here column 1-4 and 5-8 are two blocks]
only one $x_i$ is 1. Each Block has the property that each element is shifted by one index.

I copied the matrix from here:
[Minimize $\|Ax-b\|$ where $x$ is a binary vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516208/minimize-ax-b-where-x-is-a-binary-vector)
Its a slighty different objective but the matrix is basically the same.
In the comments someone say something about block matrices and the kernel which i don't fully understand. Maybe someone could explain that a litte bit more?´

Thank you

Comment: What does $\min \max Ax$ mean?

Comment: May be $||Ax||$ ?

Comment: Minimze the maximum element so the norm would be the maximum norm

Comment: Do you mean the maximum element *in absolute value*? That's a norm. But just the maximum value alone is not, in fact, a norm.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily cast as a mixed-integer linear program. Adding variables $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^6$, we have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & z \\
\text{subject to} & y_i \leq z, ~i=1,2,...6 \\
                  & A x = y \\
                  & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1 \\
                  & x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 1 \\
                  & x_i \in \{0,1\}, ~ i=1,2,\dots, 8
\end{array}$$
Any modeling framework with MILP support should have no difficulty handling this problem.

If instead you intend to minimize the maximum element *in absolute value*, you need to do this:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & z \\
\text{subject to} & -z \leq y_i \leq z, ~i=1,2,...6 \\
                  & A x = y \\
                  & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1 \\
                  & x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 1 \\
                  & x_i \in \{0,1\}, ~ i=1,2,\dots, 8
\end{array}$$

But to be honest, I can see the solution to both problems by inspection: the optimal value is $3$, and any of the the following $x$ vectors will achieve it:
$$(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)$$