# Minimizing $\|A x - b\|^2_2$ subject to $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ or $x \in \Bbb Z^n$

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following Boolean least-squares problem.

$$ \underset{x \in \{0,1\}^n}{\text{minimize}} \quad \| A x - b \|_2^2 $$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  A solution does not necessarily exist, i.e., there does not exist $x'$ such that $A x' = b$.

I have tried looking online for a solution but could not find one that suits my problem. From what I understood, algorithms like gradient descent only work with real valued vectors. Then, when I tried looking into MIP problems (for example [Minimize $\| x \|_1$ subject to $Ax=b$ where $x$ is a binary vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516208/minimize-x-1-subject-to-ax-b-where-x-is-a-binary-vector)) the goal was to minimize the norm of $x$ while supposing that a solution exists, which is different than my case.

I would like to know if there exists any way to optimize this value, and if there is any efficient way to do it. I am expecting this problem to be NP-hard from what I saw with MIP, but I am not sure yet.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755688/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/75932/53274)

Comment: It is a straightforward MIP - you write out your favourite least-squares model (QP or SOCP) and the constraints that $x$ is binary. It is NP-hard, yes.